# Prove that external direct product is isomorphic to group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, proof-writing, group-isomorphism

**Let $G$ be a group with identity $e_G$ and let $H$ be a group with identity $e_H$. Prove that $G$ is isomorphic to $G \oplus {e_H}$ and that H is isomorphic to ${e_G} \oplus H$.**

I've defined $$g: G \to G \oplus {e_H} \; \; \text{by} \; \; g(x) = (x, e_H)$$ and $$h: H \to {e_G} \oplus H  \; \; \text{by} \; \; h(x) = (e_G,x)$$

I've just learned about the external direct product and my professor wasn't available to explain it further. How do I show that my maps are 1-1 and operation preserving if I don't know the operation for $G$ and $H$? (I assume I'll be able to prove onto once I understand 1-1.)

Thanks!

Comment: First of all, you should write products as $G\times H$, since $G\oplus H$ normally denotes the direct product (direct sum) of two abelian groups.
Then, you should learn the construction of $G\times H$, e.g. from Wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_product_of_groups

Comment: To show $g$ is a homomorphism, you must show that $g(x_1x_2) = g(x_1)g(x_2)$, which in this case means showing $(x_1x_2,e_H) = (x_1,e_H)(x_2,e_H)$ (using the product in $G \times H$ of $(x_1,y_1)(x_2,y_2) = (x_1x_2,y_1y_2)$).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As already pointed out, you should write $G\times H$ rather than using $\oplus$ as that denotes something quite different. You do not need to know the specific operations because direct product is done componentwise. That is
$$(a,x)\cdot (b,x)=(a\cdot b,x\cdot y)$$
To show it is injective, or a monomorphism (which is better than 1-1 if you ask me) we simply check if the homomorphisms kernel is the trivial one. for $g$ we then have $g(x)=(e_G,e_H)$ which gives us that $x=e_G$ and as such is trivial and it is a monomorphism. Can you take it from here?